# Rails complex association: has_and_belongs_to_many from two classes to one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, migration

In my application, I have a `User` model and `Artist` model. Both `users` and `artists` should be able to "follow" multiple artists. I'm not really sure how to describe this relationship, and I'm completely lost regarding the underlying migration.

I've tried having `has_and_belongs_to_many :artists` in both classes, and an additional `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` in `Artist`, but that seems really messy, and I don't know how to write the migration.

I've looked at the [association docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) for the migration; I'm not sure if it would be simpler to have a third-class and use a `:through` association, or if I would need one for user-to-artist and another for artist-to-artist, or if one additional class would be enough.

Help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not 100% what you need, but may shed some light on the issue. http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Comment: I think it would be wiser if Artist was associated with User as an "extension" to it. Makes design much simpler.

Comment: Charles, that looks promising, I'll take a close look at it. Michael, do you mean that Artist should be a subclass of User? I had considered that, but there were other architectural reasons why that won't work in this case.

Comment: in case you do not subclass `Artist` from `User`, you will end up with two collections in `Artist`: `user_followers` and `artist_followers`. This will work, but will make for a messy domain model.